# Printjob not updating

Tags: android, printing

I need help please with updating my printJob on Android.

I am modifying the printJobInfo, specifically the setCopies parameter but the layout still reads the number of copies as 1:

---

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

PrintAttributes.Builder attbuilder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
attbuilder.setMediaSize( PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);

PrintJob newPrintJob = printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);
PrintJobInfo newPrintJobInfo = newPrintJob.getInfo();

PrintJobInfo.Builder jobBuilder = new PrintJobInfo.Builder(newPrintJobInfo);
jobBuilder.setCopies(numberOfCopies);
jobBuilder.setPages(new PageRange[] {PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
jobBuilder.setAttributes(attbuilder.build());

getActivity().getIntent().putExtra(PrintService.EXTRA_PRINT_JOB_INFO, newPrintJobInfo);
getActivity().setIntent(getActivity().getIntent());
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
```

---

However, this is not updating my printJob which keeps the attributes as null and the number of copies as 1 as seen in the .

Any ideas please???

Comment: As seen in the Android Print UI

Answer (score 0):

Which Android version are you testing on? According to this Android [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37054219), PrintAttributes were ignored. This should be fixed in N+ devices

Comment: Actually, I am not having any issues with the PrintAttributes (mode, paper size, color .. etc.) .. it's just the setCopies which is related/changed from the PrintJob itself but it is not updating with the jobBuilder (even after adding jobBuilder.build())

Comment: If all other attributes except copy are correctly reflected you may want to open an Android bug.