# PrintAttributes not working. not able to create custom page size

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

I am struggling with google printing interface in tablet. I want a print of fixed page size. `PrintAttributes.Builder` is not modifying the page and margin settings. How can i create a new custom/fixed page dimension for print. Now It shows **ISO_A4** by default for HP printer.

My code is below:

```
PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
PrintAttributes.MediaSize custom = new PrintAttributes.MediaSize("VISIT_K" , "VISIT_K", 86000,139860);
custom.asPortrait();
builder.setMediaSize( custom );
printJob = printManager.print(jobName, adapter,
builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Which Android version are you testing on? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47560952/1098917) concerning a bug pre- Android 7
Regardless, the attributes here serve only as "hints", from the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#print-adapter):

> You can use this parameter to provide hints to the printing framework
>   and pre-set options based on the previous printing cycle, thereby
>   improving the user experience. You may also use this parameter to set
>   options that are more appropriate to the content being printed, such
>   as setting the orientation to landscape when printing a photo that is
>   in that orientation.

I think if it conflicts with what the printer is reporting as supported/default, the printer's attributes may take precedence. This could be a feature/bug report to Android if it is not otherwise working.